# Do you have to specify the table for an abstract and table-less baseclass when using union-subclass with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance, nhibernate-mapping

We have a BaseEntity of which all our other domain classes inherit. On this BaseEntity are some basic properties. This could be something like `DateLastChange` for example.

We're using NHibernate with `hbm` mapping files. I'm trying to avoid having to map `DateLastChange` in every mapping file.

I found [this post](http://ayende.com/blog/3941/nhibernate-mapping-inheritance) by Ayende, which makes me believe I could use `union-subclass` to achieve this (see his last approach). However, he includes a table name for his abstract class, that isn't in his table-schema.

```
<class name="Party"
    abstract="true"
    table="Parties">
...
```

Does the table have to exist, or will NHibernate just ignore this attribute? And can I then omit it?

Comment: Typo. check out http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not needed. As per the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete) (thanks to kalki):

```
<class name="Payment">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="PAYMENT_ID">
        <generator class="sequence"/>
    </id>
    <property name="amount" column="AMOUNT"/>
    ...
    <union-subclass name="CreditCardPayment" table="CREDIT_PAYMENT">
        <property name="creditCardType" column="CCTYPE"/>
        ...
    </union-subclass>
    <union-subclass name="CashPayment" table="CASH_PAYMENT">
        ...
    </union-subclass>
    <union-subclass name="ChequePayment" table="CHEQUE_PAYMENT">
        ...
    </union-subclass>
</class>
```

And:

> If your superclass is abstract, map it with abstract="true". If it is
>   not abstract, an additional table (it defaults to PAYMENT in the
>   example above), is needed to hold instances of the superclass.

Answer (score -1):

I have the following abstract class in fluentnhibernate:

```
    public abstract class EntityMapping<TEntity> : ClassMap<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityBase
        {
            protected EntityMapping()
            {
                Id(x => x.Id, "Id")
                    .UnsavedValue("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
                    .GeneratedBy.GuidComb()
                    .Index("IX_Lookup");
                OptimisticLock.Version();
                Version(x => x.Version);
Map(x=>x.DateLastChange); // your column
            }
        }
```

all other mappings use the abstract class:

```
public SomeEntityMap:EntityMapping<SomeEntity>{
   public SomeEntityMap(){
      Map(x=>x.SomeProperty);
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see how this helps me. I'm specifically looking for a solution using union-subclass and hbm.xml files. I also have a specific inheritance approach I want to use.

Comment: Never read the hbm part in the question. Curious as to why you would still be using hbm files with both fluent and confORM available